# Email address change

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We're using salesforce accounts for journeys in MC. Those Salesforce accounts have additional information like Campaigns,Opportubities etc. linked within Sales Cloud we're using in MC. We're using Sales Cloud id as SubscriberKey.

What is a common way to handle email address changes from sales cloud? As I understand, it's not possible to update the subscribers E-Mail address within MC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to update the changed email addresses from sales/service cloud on a regular basis is creating a scheduled automation, containing these four activities (might seem strange, but currently is the best way to do this):

- **SQL Query Activity** (checks for changed email addresses in your synchronized data extensions and writes them to a temporary data extension)
- **Data Extract Activity** (extracts the data from your temporary data extension and writes it to a CSV-file, which is placed in your account’s Enhanced FTP)
- **File Transfer Activity** (moves the CSV-file from activity 2 to the Import-folder of your Enhanced FTP, so Marketing Cloud can process it)
- **Import File Activity** (imports the data from the CSV-file to the All Subscribers list)

I recently published an [article regarding this email address update automation on my blog](https://markus.codes/2017/07/14/how-to-sync-email-changes-from-service-cloud-to-all-subscribers-list). Maybe you might want to check it out for an even more detailed description.